# Real-time updates from server to client

Tags: ios, sockets, socket.io, apple-push-notifications

I'm looking for solution how to send data from server to client in real-time. I have client (ios app) which communicate with my server, and I need to send some data from server to client when something has changed on server.

I know about APNS and about sockets. But what is the best solution: APNS or sockets? Is that normal practice to use push notifications while client is in foreground?

I'm new to real-time updates on client side, so please do not judge strictly.